# Issue setting a RealmList<Object> to my database item, using Realm for android

Tags: android, database, web-services, gson, realm

First I call a function that will bring back my user from the database, and after I get my updated profile from the WS, and I try to change the list of friends from the database.

Method to get my user:

```
 public UserRecord getMyUser(){
    String userId = PSLocationCenter.getInstance().pref.getUserId(context);
    RealmResults<UserRecord> completed = realm.where(UserRecord.class).equalTo("id" , userId).findAll();
    if(completed.size() > 0){
        return completed.get(0);
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

After that , this is the WSCall from which I get the data, and try to change the friends list:

```
user = UserRecordDBFactory.getInstance(PSProfileActivity.this).getMyUser();
WSCalls.getData("/api/users/" + user.getId() + "/friends", PSProfileActivity.this, loader, new JsonCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                            try {
                                FriendsResponse friendsResponse = JsonUtil.jsonToObject(jsonObject.toString(), FriendsResponse.class);
                                Log.i("","friends response: " + friendsResponse.toString());
                                Log.i("","friends response: " + friendsResponse.getFriends());
                                friends = friendsResponse.getFriends();
                                Log.i("","friends after being given the response: " + friends.size());
                                Log.i("","friends USER after being given the response: " + user);
                                Log.i("","friends USER after being given the response: " + user.getId());
                                Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(PSProfileActivity.this);
                                realm.beginTransaction();
                                user.setFriends(friends);
                                Log.i("", "friends set to user: " + friends);
                                realm.commitTransaction();
                                UserRecordDBFactory.getInstance(PSProfileActivity.this).updateMyUser(user);
                                Log.i("", "friends set to user in REALM: " + friends);
                                setHeaderAndData(profile);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Utils.appendLog("onresume friends activ error: " + e.getMessage());
                                Log.e("", "getProfileData - JsonException: " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

This is the log I get back:

```
03-10 18:02:13.826  23882-23882/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ friends response: nl.hgrams.passenger.model.FriendsResponse@1635594a
03-10 18:02:13.827  23882-23882/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ friends response: RealmList@[254263483,474495448,561029425,720879638,789032343,921901956,66920301,229099426,948931635,877161456,1062815081,73317358,28096655,610293532,322424613,192850170,667307691]
03-10 18:02:13.827  23882-23882/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ friends after being given the response: 17
03-10 18:02:13.829  23882-23882/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ friends USER after being given the response: UserRecord = [{username:},{first_name:Alin},{last_name:Red},{email:r@y.com},{token:8596bcb0243cc16b6f16e5e90210754c65f8e58ca426daecd3d7220d5092e24d},{id:6},{bio:Red},{image:/media/user_image/8b824838993f3c5aae2bfb650851e7e1.jpe},{nrTrips:0},{distance:0},{last_destination:},{friends:RealmList<Friend>[0]},{activityLog:null},{recents:RealmList<SearchData>[0]},{updateRecents:false}]
03-10 18:02:13.829  23882-23882/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ friends USER after being given the response: 6
03-10 18:02:13.836  23882-23882/nl.hgrams.passenger E/﹕ getProfileData - JsonException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long io.realm.internal.Row.getIndex()' on a null object reference
```

This is my setter from the RealmObject class:

```
public void setFriends(RealmList<Friend> fr) {
    Log.i("","before in set friends");
    friends = fr;
    Log.i("","after in set friends");
}
```

And it doesn't log neither of the logs from the getter. As you can see I also made logs to check if user or friends are null, but it's not the case.
Any ideea what I'm doing wrong here?
Seeing that it tried long io.realm.internal.Row.getIndex(), I'm guessing it finds the user somehow null, but why?

This is what the jsonToObject function does:

```
public static <T> T jsonToObject(String json, Class<T> toClass) throws Exception {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new JsonUtil();
    }
    return instance.gson.fromJson(json, toClass);
}
```

Where the instance gson is:

```
gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                    return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .create();
```

And I only have RealmObjects inside my UserRecord, I do not use normal objects

Comment: What does JsonUtil.jsonToObject(jsonObject.toString(), FriendsResponse.class) do_ The error you are getting is most likely because you are mixing RealmObjects and stand alone objects. For user.setFriends() to work, they must first be proper RealmObjects as well, eg. by using Realm.copyToRealm.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior made an edit, and included the code for the jsonToObject function. Also checked and there is normal objects. What I was thinking about, is that I created the objects but didn't really copyToRealm, as in this objects I do not want to keep. Could that be the source of the problem?

Comment: The realmlist from the item is a realm backedup realmlist, but the other one, is a standalone realmlist, How can I make my standalone realmlist be a realm backed up one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can avoid iterating over all of your friends and add them individually if you do something like this:

```
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            List<Friend> realmFriends = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(friends);
            RealmList<Message> realmListFriends = new RealmList<>(realmFriends.toArray(new Friend[friends.size()]));
            user.setFriends(realmListFriends);
        }
    });
```

EDIT: Just to be clear, you are still iterating over your friends internally inside the method Collection.toArray(). The complexity is still O(n), but the code is more readable

Answer (score 1):

Did it like this and it worked:

```
WSCalls.getData("/api/users/" + user.getId() + "/friends", PSProfileActivity.this, loader, new JsonCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                            try {
                                FriendsResponse friendsResponse = JsonUtil.jsonToObject(jsonObject.toString(), FriendsResponse.class);
                                Log.i("","friends response: " + friendsResponse.getFriends());
                                Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(PSProfileActivity.this);
                                friends = friendsResponse.getFriends();
                                for (UserRecord friend : friends) {
                                    friend.setDistanceTraveled(friend.getStats().getDistanceTraveled());
                                }
                                Log.i("","first begin transaction");
                                realm.beginTransaction();
                                List<UserRecord> list = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(friends);
                                realm.commitTransaction();

                                Log.i("", "second begin transaction");
                                realm.beginTransaction();
                                user.getFriends().clear();
                                for (UserRecord friend : list) {
                                    user.getFriends().add(friend);
                                }
                                realm.commitTransaction();
                                Log.i("", "third begin transaction");

                                setHeaderAndData(profile);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Utils.appendLog("onresume friends activ error: " + e.getMessage());
                                Log.e("", "getProfileData - JsonException: " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Needed to first copy the list to the realm, then use the managed items to add on my item, in order to then commit my item